# scala shorthand for matching one case class

Tags: scala

Is there really no simple idiomatic way of checking whether an object is a certain class, other than using `.isInstanceOf[ClassName]` or a full match expression?

A match for a single class may avoid the need for using `.AsInstanceOf` (when necessary for acting on class-unique members), but is very verbose in general and in requiring to explicitly cover for the default case...

Perhaps there would be some library for working with class hierarchies that simplifies assigning classes to objects and checking for them, to bypass the scala core class matcher limitations. I even considered implementing my own type assignment, hierarchies and checking solution, using plain collections, rather than using scala classes, for rich hierarchical type modeling that feels more idiomatic.

Comment: Anything to look for in Scalaz or Shapeless in this context?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not. The syntax was deliberately made verbose because having to use this feature often indicates a bad design.

It is possible, however, to write a function yourself:

```
implicit class WithAs[T](x: T) {
  import scala.reflect._
  def as[O: ClassTag]: Option[O] = x match {
    case o: O => Some(o)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

<kbd>[live demo](http://ideone.com/NsIxgE)</kbd>

Comment: Maybe I do not fully grasp why it indicates bad design to check the type of an object rather than handle multiple cases in one (match) code block. I'd appreciate some deleneation. By the way will the above code withstand type erasure?

Comment: The design implications are easy: type-testing by definition implies coding toward a special case.  Special cases are extremely likely break as your code evolves, and make your code difficult to reason about.

Comment: @DaveGriffith a link to a wider exposition of special case avoidance with regard to object oriented modelling, would be much appreciated.